# what is the best way to automate the deployment of a containerized game server from github to google cloud run

Tags: docker, github, docker-compose, dockerfile, google-compute-engine

I have a containerized game server running on UDP port in my github repo.I need to deploy it on google cloud.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot deploy a UDP application to Google Cloud Run.

[Google Cloud Run - FAQ](https://github.com/ahmetb/cloud-run-faq)

**Cloud Run only supports HTTP/1.x and HTTP/2 (including gRPC) over TLS**. Other TCP and UDP based protocols are not supported. This means, you can't run your arbitrary TCP based application, or a Redis/Memcached server on Cloud Run.

Comment: thanks for the answer.Can we deploy it on kubernetes ?in clusters?

Comment: @FreddySome - Please create a new question for Kubernetes.